# Recursing two linked list simultaneously

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

I'm currently trying to create a recursive two linked lists function that returns single value of linked lists value simultaneously.

For example, having two linked lists: ll1 -> a, b, c and ll2 -> d, e, f

It will return a, d, b, e, f recursively, (there's code segment what I'm trying to do below, which will make more sense!)

```
class LinkedList:
    created = 0
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next
        LinkedList.created  += 1

def convert_linked_list(l):
    if l == []:
        return None
    front = rear = LinkedList(l[0])
    for v in l[1:]:
        rear.next = LinkedList(v)
        rear = rear.next
    return front

def convert_linked_str(ll):
    answer = ''
    while ll != None:
        answer += str(ll.value)+'->'
        ll = ll.next
    return answer + 'None'
```

This is my recursive linked list function, I wrote so far.

```
def recursive_lls(ll1: LinkedList, ll2: LinkedList) -> LinkedList:
    if ll1 == None or ll2 == None:
        return None
    else:
        alternate = LinkedList(ll1.value, recursive_lls(ll1.next, ll2.next))
    return alternate

ll1 = convert_linked_list(['n',3 ,'z','d'])
ll2 = convert_linked_list(['w','x',7 ,'g','e',1])
print(convert_linked_str(recursive_lls(ll1,ll2)))
```

It will give me a result of :

```
n->3->z->d->None
```

But the desired result is:

```
n->w->3->x->z->7->d->g->e->1->None
```

- Result always begin with ll1 head value
- ll1 and ll2 can be uneven length, if ll2 values run out then ll1 keeps going (can be other way around)

What will be the best way to approach this recursive function with what I have currently? I know using classes instead of helper functions will be easier.

- Has to be recursive, no looping
- No fancy imports (zips etc)

Also if its **single** recursive linked list function, this is what I wrote below. But with two linked list, I am really confused how to.

```
def single_recursive_ll(ll):
    if ll == None:
        return None
    elif ll.next == None:
        return LN(ll.value)
    else:
        return_ll = LN(ll.value, single_recursive_ll(ll.next))
        if return_ll.value == return_ll.next.value:
            return_ll = return_ll.next
return return_ll
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `recursive_lls` function has a few problems.

1. It terminates when either `ll1` or `ll2` is `None`
2. In the call to `LinkedList`, `recursive_lls` does not alternate the linked list in the first argument position. Furthermore, it is always advancing the second linked list **so what you get in the end is the minimum linked list in `ll1` whoes length is no longer than the length of `ll2`**

The fix is as follows:

1. Adjust the base case of the recursive calls so both linked lists are pinted fully.
2. Adjust the recursive call to ensure the lists are actually alternated.

The following code does just that

```
def recursive_lls(ll1: LinkedList, ll2: LinkedList) -> LinkedList:
    if ll1 == None:
        return ll2
    if ll2 == None:
        return ll1
    else:
        alternate = LinkedList(ll1.value, recursive_lls(ll2, ll1.next))
    return alternate
```

The test shows it now runs as expected:

```
>>> ll1 = convert_linked_list(['n',3 ,'z','d'])
>>> ll2 = convert_linked_list(['w','x',7 ,'g','e',1])
>>> print(convert_linked_str(recursive_lls(ll1,ll2)))
n->w->3->x->z->7->d->g->e->1->None
```